# CSS Change "content" of previous sibling's after

Tags: html, css

I have the following html structure ( i cannot change , generated by JS ) :

```
<ul>
<li>
  <a>
    <span class="current-info">Step X: </span>
    <span class="number">1.</span>
    <span class="booking-icon">Date</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a>
    <span class="current-info">Step X: </span>
    <span class="number">2.</span>
    <span class="calendar-icon">Date</span>
  </a>
</li>
...
```

And class "number" has the following css by default:

```
#bds-bf.wizard > .steps > ul > li.current > .number:after{
content: '\f2b4';
font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Class "number" is repeated many times, so i cannot change content based on it.
What i want to do is change the value of

```
#bds-bf.wizard > .steps > ul > li.current > .number:after
```

based on its **sibling's class**  , so for example if it found **.booking-icon** class in the next sibling it should make content like:

```
content: "\f0f9'
```

How can i achieve this with css selectors without using Javascript ?

UPDATED: JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/s4wje415/

Comment: Can you create fiddle for testing purposes? Thanks

Comment: I believe you cannot find the previous class in css like `.booking-icon < .number:after` **it is not working**. What you can do is finding the next sibling by `+`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Comment: @HermLuna I updated with a jsfiddle

Comment: @AbhishekPandey i understand that it's not necessarily done by selection previous but some other tricks like siblings check could make it work , can't figure out how yet

Comment: @ZayLau can i find next sibling but "select" the current one , not the next ?

Comment: I have updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s4wje415/1/ , take a look, may it can help you.